# How to get linked beans function in SuiteCRM

Tags: suitecrm

I want to setup email notification in suitecrm. I have created the logic hook and email notification php file. However my issue is that when it reaches this line $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was issued to: ". $bean->name); it throws the error message. But I'm not understanding as to why it throws the error message if me syntax is incorrect.

```
class nc_email_notification {
public function email_notification(&$bean, $events, $arguments){

/*define 'review_pending' as  string constant */

/*Get sugar email engine*/
$email = new SugarPHPMailer();
$email->From = 'suitecrm@gmail.com';
$email->FromName ='SuiteCRM';

/*Get the Department NC was Issued to */
$dept_array= $bean->get_linked_beans('dept_department_nccas_nc_case','dept_Department_sugar');

if(count($dept_array)==0){      
    /*log error*/
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was issued to: ". $bean->name);
}else{
    /* Get email of users within the Department NC is issued to */              
    $user_array = $dept_array[0]->get_linked_beans('dept_department_users','User');
    if(count($user_array)==0){      
        /*log error*/
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find Users within the department NC is issued to: ". $bean->name);
    }else{
        $address=getDepartmentUsersEmail($user_array);
    }


    /*Get the Department NC was raised by */
    $raised_dept_array= $bean->get_linked_beans('dept_department_nccas_nc_case_1','dept_Department_sugar'); 
    if(count($raised_dept_array)==0){       
        /*log error*/
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find the department NC was raised by: ". $bean->name);
    }else {
        /*Get email of users within the Department NC is raised by*/
        $raised_user_array = $raised_dept_array[0]->get_linked_beans('dept_department_users','User');
        if(count($raised_user_array)==0){       
            /*log error*/
            $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Could not find Users within the department NC is raised by: ". $bean->name);
        }
        else {
            $r_user_address = getDepartmentUsersEmail($raised_user_array);              
        }
    }


    /*Get the Quality Systems Department*/
    //$qual_dept=$dept_array[0]->retrieve)by)string_fields(array('name' => 'Quality Systems' ));
    //$qual_dept->load_relationship('dept_department_email_addresses_primary');

    /* Send email to Manager */
    $rev_email = 'ramon@gmail.com';


    /*Get NC Action for the NC Case*/
    $action_array = $bean->get_linked_beans('nccas_nc_case_ncact_nc_action','ncact_NC_Action_sugar');

    /* Get sugar template engine */
    $xtpl = new XTemplate("XTemplate/NCEmailTemplate.html");

    /*GEt the URL for the NC Case */
    $url =  $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['site_url'].'index.php?module=ncase_NonConformance&action=DetailView&record='.$bean->id; 
    $xtpl -> assign('URL', $url);

    /* Get NC Status */
    $nc_status=trim($bean->getFieldValue('status'));

    /* Get NC ID */
    $id = $bean->getFieldValue('id');

    if(empty($bean->fetched_row['id'])){

        $email=createNCEmail($email,$rev_email,'New NC Email Notification',$bean,$xtpl);                

        /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
        $email->addaddress($rev_email);

        /* Send email to users of Issued to department  */
        foreach($address as $uemail){                       
            $email->addAddress($uemail);
        }

        }else {
            if (strcasecmp ($nc_status,'review_pending')==0){
                /* Set Email Subject */
                $email->Subject = 'NC Case: '. ''. $bean->name . ' '. ' is pending review';

                /* Send email to users of Raised by department  */
                foreach($r_user_address as $uemail){                        
                    $email->addAddress($uemail);
                }
                /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
                $email->addaddress($rev_email);


                /* Create email message using email template */
                $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

            } else if (strcasecmp ($nc_status,'Closed')==0){
                    /* Set Email Subject */
                    $email->Subject = 'NC Case: '. ''. $bean->name . ''. ' is Closed';

                    /* Send email to users of Raised by department  */
                    foreach($r_user_address as $uemail){                        
                        $email->addAddress($uemail);
                    }                       
                    /* Send email to Issued to Department */
                    foreach($address as $iemail){                       
                        $email->addAddress($iemail);
                    }

                    /* Create email message using email template*/
                    $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

            } else{

                    If ($bean->fetched_row['description'] != $bean->description){
                    /* Set Email Subject */
                    $email->Subject = 'NC Case: ' .''. $bean->name .''. ' has been modified';

                    /* Create email message using email template */
                    $email=createNCEmailwithAction($email,$action_array,$bean,$xtpl);

                    /* Build appropriate email list */
                    foreach($address as $uemail){                       
                        $email->addAddress($uemail);
                    }
                    /* Send email to Quality System Manager */
                    $email->addaddress($rev_email);

                }
            }
    }
```

Logic Hook

```
$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Create NC email object', 'custom/Extension/modules/ncase_NonConformance/Ext/email_notification.php','nc_email_notification', 'email_notification');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I know nothing about the name of your fields.

First check the '`dept_department_nccas_nc_case`'(should be `$field_name`) and '`dept_Department_sugar`'(should be `$bean_name`).
Also you can try to use [load_relationship](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/working-with-beans/)